# Point shapefile is not displaying

Tags: arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system

I have created a point shapefile in ArcGIS 10.0 that has a geographic projection, but it will not display/draw. When I view the properties it has no "extent" information. Is this the problem?

Comment: Please indicate what software you are using.

Comment: what's your software ? do you only created a shapefile or add point to the shapefile using editor tools ?

Comment: I am using arcgis 10.0; exported data from one point shapefile to another one; made some edits to the "new" file(deleted 2 rows); saved edits, etc.

Comment: see the shapefile attribute . if you don't have any rows then you dont have any points in the shapefile . if you see the row(s) in the attribute , i think you have a problem in geometry . use repair geometry tool (ArcToolbox=>Data management tools=> features=> repair geometry

Comment: Try deleting/creating the spatial index too.

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Comment: @mkennedy Good call, I recently had an extent error issue and deleting the .sbn file solve the issue.

Comment: What were your precise steps used to create your shapefile?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is actually data (rows) in the file and it is just not showing, you can try fixing the point data manually by:

- creating POINT_X and POINT_Y columns
- using "calculate geometry" write the x and y popint coordinates into those fields respectively
- export that attribute table as a text file
- reimport it back into your map
- right cick and display x-y data using the centroid locations as the x and y coordinates

You can then export the data and you have a new point shapefile.